# Apache suddenly stops serving to LAN computers, now only localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, lan

## TLDR: **Apache *WAS* serving pages to LAN computers, but suddenly only works on localhost.**

#### Background info:

*(I discovered the WAMP, XAMPP, etc packages a day after)* **I built a WAMP server individually, with**

- Windows 7 HomePremium 64-bit
- Apache 2.2.21
- PHP 5.2.17
- MySQL 5.5

I will include httpd.conf, php.ini, errorlogs, host file, w/e you need, just tell me if you'd like it on a codepaste site, or inline here.

Thank you's:
I have had tons of problems and questions in the month I've been building/running this server, and almost invariably S/O was the best/fastest/easiest place with the RIGHT answers, so thank you to this community. =)

(I'm not positive if this is better asked on webapps.stackexchange.com/, but all my WAMP search results have been on SO, so..)

> > EDIT: I found serverfault, and [cross-posted](https://serverfault.com/questions/360690/apache-suddenly-stops-serving-to-lan-computers-now-only-localhost) this there. I'm leaving it here though, because this is where most of my answers before have come from, **and I genuinely mean the Thank You for all the help in the last month!**

Answer (score 2):

Check the Listen directives in ports.conf. There may only be one entry for localhost (127.0.0.1:80). If so, add `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`, and restart.